# How do I set the URL from localhost to localhost/applicationOne in Visual Studio?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-2013

I have a web application that at the moment is running on http://localhost if I use Visual Studio to run the solution.

I would like to change the settings so that VS starts running it on http://localhost/applicationOne as the starting point.

I want to replicate an issue that seems to be happening only if the web application is deployed to a directory that is not of the root directory in an IIS server.

How do I go about doing this?

Answer (score 0):

You can edit the properties of the project, and set the **Project Url**.

**If using Local IIS**

[image]

Note: this will require Visual Studio to be run as an Administrator.  Behind the scenes, a virtual directory will be created in IIS, and launching the project (e.g. via debugging with F5) will launch the browser, using the Url specified here.

**If using IIS Express**

[image]

Effectively the same settings apply with IIS Express.  Note the port number in the Url.

Comment: You can also do this with IIS Express.

Comment: Ah of course.  Updated to show the (subtle) differences.